# How to get current local time with Zend

Tags: magento-1.9, zend-framework

I need to get the current local time of the customer's location. 
 One method is to do it by: `Mage::getModel('core/date')`. 
 
 But I need to extract the day number and current time from it, which can be done very nicely by `Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_DIGIT` and 
`Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT`,
 but the "current time placeholder" for Zend is: `Zend_Date::now();` which takes the current time of the server and not the customer. 
 
 Is there a way I can use these Zend functions with `Mage::getModel('core/date')` timestamp, and if not, how do I achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out a way myself!

```
$time = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp()); 
$day_number = $time->get(Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_DIGIT);
$current_time = $time->get(Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT);
```

Can also be done without Zend:

```
$time = Mage::getModel('core/date'); 
$day_number = $time->date('N'); 
$current_time = $time->date('H:i');
```